# Passing multiple words in onclick() function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to pass a string that contains few words to jQuery when click on the link.
It works with parameters that are integers or single words, but when the parameter is a string that consists of few words, the function does not execute.
Example:

```
$name='Steve';
$fullName='Steve Jobs';

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send(<? echo $name; ?>)">Link 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send(<? echo $fullName; ?>)">Link 2</a>
```

Javascript code:

```
function send(name){
    alert (name);
}
```

***Link 1*** works.
***Link 2*** does not work.
How to make ***Link 2*** to work?

Comment: Show the code in `send()`. You haven't given enough information to be able to answer your question.

Comment: View source and paste the rendered HTML please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the echo'd variables since they are to be interpreted as strings, not javascript variable names:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send('<? echo $name; ?>')">Link 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send('<? echo $fullName; ?>')">Link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the `<?echo ... ?>`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send('<? echo $name; ?>')">Link 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send('<? echo $fullName; ?>')">Link 2</a>
```